# How to remove git-svn from git repo?

Tags: git, svn

I started working on a project 2 years ago and I chose SVN as the revision control system. Then in last year I decided to switch from SVN to GIT via `git svn clone`. From then on, I never commit to old SVN repo again. I'm the only one using the repo so there is no branchs in both SVN and GIT.

Now I want to remove the **git-svn** tag here: (I'm not sure if it is a tag.)
[image: git log]

**All the commits and logs in old SVN repo must be retained.**

What should I do? I'm using TortoiseGit and knows just a little about git commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution: just delete `refs/remotes/git-svn` in the context menu.

[image]

And then remove the folder `.git/svn`.

All histroy will be maintained.

Comment: This is because git-svn is just a remote reference (branch), not a commit. I would recommend you to use a better graph visualization tool  as this representation is rather misleading.

Comment: I thought the commits and logs before __git-svn__ still existed in old svn repo instead of new git repo by `git svn clone`, and after removing the __git-svn__ all these commits and logs would be lost. But actually it is __not__ the case.

Comment: ... true! Because with git you are always working only on your local copy of the repository. Nothing is changed in the outer world unless you `push`. Welcome to git :-)

Comment: this may come in useful to someone...I kept seeing the `SVN DCommit` options in the context menus of Tortoise Git, even after deleting the `ref/remotes/git-svn` mainly the show log dialog. I found a SVN folder in the hidden .git folder. After deleting the SVN folder the `SVN DCommit` options were gone from context menu. Which is what I was after.

Comment: @MattFricker "And then remove the folder .git/svn."